# error[E0412]: cannot find type `ProgramResult` in this scope

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, anchor-solana

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod myepicproject {
  use super::*;
  pub fn start_stuff_off(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> ProgramResult {
    Ok(())
  }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct StartStuffOff {}
```

I have the source rust code above and the error below.

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `ProgramResult` in this scope
 --> programs/myepicproject/src/lib.rs:8:58
  |
8 |   pub fn start_stuff_off(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> ProgramResult {
  |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0412`.
error: could not compile `myepicproject` due to previous error
```

Have any suggestion?

Using Anchor

Comment: The last version with `ProgramResult` was `anchor_lang` v0.21.0 [It looks like from `0.22.0` and on you're supposed to use just `Result<()>` instead](https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-1)

Comment: I used Result<()> instead ProgramResult.

But have warning.

I'm newbie on Rust development and this is the first step of my learning Rust.

Please tell me more detail and specifically.

Comment: What is the warning that you are getting? As long as your compilation doesn't fail; the code should work as expected. Most warnings from the compiler will notify you when you violate best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like that:

```
pub fn start_stuff_off(ctx: Context<StartStuffOff>) -> Result<()> {
```

Answer (score 10):

this solves the issue. you have to explicitly import it

```
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;
```